# Updating the object based on the presence of the key else form a new object : Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Have an object with following format:

```js
let obj = {
  p2: {
    p21: [
      {
        key1: "val1",
        value1: "val2"
      },
      {
        prop: "test",
        value: "dummy"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I basically have to see if there is an object that has key "prop" and replace with whatever the passed value. If such key does not present create an object with `{ "prop" : "test" , value: passed_value}` and add it to the p21 array. Also this object containing key "prop" can be present anywhere inside p21 array

Should be something like this

```js
function checkAndUpdate(replacingValue) {
    if(obj's p21 has key name "prop")
    {
      //update its "value" to the passed "replacingValue"

    }
    else //if "prop" key not present
    {
       // create an object with { "prop": "test" , value: replacingValue} and add it to p21 array        
    }  
  }
```

Have tried following:

```js
obj.p2.p21.map((elem) => {
    if(Object.keys(elem)[0] === "prop") 
        elem.value = updateValue;
})
```

Comment: you need to check in `p21` array or key can be anywhere in the object?

Comment: @AZ_ check in p21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.findIndex` to find the index of the matching object. If it exists, `.slice` the array before and after it, and in the middle, insert the updated object. Otherwise, just spread the object into the array:

```js
let obj = {
  "p2": {
    "p21": [{
        "key1": "val1",
        "value1": "val2",
      },
      {
        "prop": "test",
        "value": "dummy"
      }
    ]
  }
}

function checkAndUpdate(value) {
  const newObj = { prop: 'test', value} 
  const arr = obj.p2.p21;
  const index = arr.findIndex(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
  const newArr = index !== -1
    ? [...arr.slice(0, index), newObj, ...arr.slice(index + 1)]
    : [...arr, newObj];
  const fullNewObj = {
    ...obj,
    p2: {
      ...obj.p2,
      p21: newArr
    }
  };
  return fullNewObj;
}
console.log(checkAndUpdate('foo'));
```

To also check whether the `value` is undefined, and remove the matching object from the array if so, just make the appropriate `if` checks, and slice the array as needed:

```js
let obj = {
  "p2": {
    "p21": [{
        "key1": "val1",
        "value1": "val2",
      },
      {
        "prop": "test",
        "value": "dummy"
      }
    ]
  }
}

function checkAndUpdate(value) {
  const newObj = { prop: 'test', value} 
  const arr = obj.p2.p21;
  const index = arr.findIndex(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
  const newArr = (() => {
    if (index === -1) {
      if (value === undefined) {
        return arr;
      }
      return [...arr, newObj];
    }
    if (value === undefined) {
      return [...arr.slice(0, index), ...arr.slice(index + 1)];
    }
    return [...arr.slice(0, index), newObj, ...arr.slice(index + 1)];
  })();
  const fullNewObj = {
    ...obj,
    p2: {
      ...obj.p2,
      p21: newArr
    }
  };
  return fullNewObj;
}
console.log(checkAndUpdate('foo'));
```

Comment: we could use  find instead of findIndex that could return object directly?

Comment: Problem with `.find` is that you need to replace the prior object in the array (at least, if you're using a standard React setup in which mutation is forbidden) - for that, you need to find the index of the element in the array, so that you can slice and clone the array properly, and insert the new object in the middle

Comment: would you help me with this edit? basically have to see if there is an object that has key "prop" and replace with whatever the passed value. If such key does not present create an object with { "prop" : "test" , value: passed_value} and add it to the p21 array. Also if "value" passed to the function is empty, remove the object with key "prop" i.e., remove this object from the original{ "prop": "test", "value": "dummy" };

Comment: when I pass checkAndUpdate(" ") it is not removing the object. since the value is empty it should remove {"prop" : "test , "value":"foo"} but it is setting value to "".  https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-mirzakhani-pogpw-so-gksmc

Comment: I thought that by `Also if "value" passed to the function is empty` you meant that if `value` is `undefined`. If you want to test if it's a *truthy* one-character long string instead (which is quite weird IMO), then just replace the `undefined`s with `' '`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.find` to find the object that `hasOwnProperty` `prop` and update

```js
let obj = {
  "p2": {
    "p21": [{
      "key1": "val1",
      "value1": "val2",
    },
    {
      "prop": "test",
      "value": "dummy"
    }
    ]
  }
}
function rep(value) {
  if (!value.length) {
    obj.p2.p21 = [...obj.p2.p21].filter(e => e.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
    return;
  }
  let ele = obj.p2.p21.find(e => e.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
  if (ele) {
    ele.value = value
    return;
  }
  obj.p2.p21.push({
    "prop": "test",
    value
  })
}

rep('test');
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
rep('');
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Comment: This will mutate the existing object, and given that this is React, that's almost certainly forbidden

Comment: @CertainPerformance didn't see `React`. I will assume OP is using some tool to create a deep copy before using this implementation. until asked

Comment: change `if (ele)` to `if (ele && value.length)`

Comment: then in start of the function, you can simply `if(!value.length) return;`

Comment: @AZ_ that still doesnt remove the object .basically have to see if there is an object that has key "prop" and replace with whatever the passed value. If such key does not present create an object with { "prop" : "test" , value: passed_value} and add it to the p21 array. Also if "value" passed to the function is empty, remove the object with key "prop" i.e., remove this object from the original{ "prop": "test", "value": "dummy" }